# About delegates in c++

Tags: c++

How do I specify the parameter of a method as any class that implements a specific interface ?

This is rather common in objective c.

Comment: There are no interfaces in C++, so the question doesn't really make sense. Could you post sample code that you're trying to get to work?

Comment: @mat - c++ has a generally accepted concept of an interface - pure virtual methods.

Comment: are you wanting to know about function pointers?

Comment: Not to mention the VC's keyword __interface.

Comment: You can either 1) define an abstract base class, and take a pointer/reference to that abstract base class, or 2) use a template, which will work with anything that supports the required member functions, operators, etc.

Comment: You might be better off describing what you're trying to achieve: the title talks about delegates, but the question body talks about interfaces. If you describe what you're trying to use this *for*, we can probably tell you how it would normally be done in C++, which might save you a lot of headaches

Answer (score 3):

There are no interfaces in standard C++, but we can simulate them pretty easily:

```
class IComparable
{
protected:
    IComparable() {};
public:
    virtual ~IComparable() = 0 {};
    virtual int Compare(const IComparable& other) const = 0;
};
```

There is no way we can instantiate this class.  It is effectively an interface.  You can then derive concrete classes from this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an "interface" or abstract base class called `Base`, then a function which can accept any object implementing that interface would look like:

```
void fn(Base& obj) {
    /*use Base functions on obj...*/
}
```